# $\lim_{x \to 0+} w(a, \delta) = 0$ iff f is continuous at $a$

Tags: continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $\Bbb R$ and $a\in \Bbb R$. For $\delta > 0$, let $w(a, \delta) = Sup|f(x) - f(a)|$, $x \in [a - \delta , a + \delta]$. Then prove:

1. $w(a, \delta_1) \leq w(a, \delta_2)$ if $\delta_1 \leq \delta_2$.
2. $\lim_{\delta \to 0+} w(a, \delta) = 0$, $\forall a \in R$.
3. $\lim_{\delta \to 0+} w(a, \delta)$ need not exist.
4. $\lim_{\delta \to 0+} w(a, \delta) = 0$ iff f is continuous at $a$

My Attempt: Let $f$ is continuous at $a$ iff 
$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$ iff 
$\lim_{x \to a} (f(x) - f(a)) = 0$ iff supremum of $|f(x) - f(a)|$ tends to $0$ as x tends to $a$. I have no idea how to Prove or Disprove other options. Please help me.

Comment: 1) and 4) are true. 2) and 3) are false.

Comment: I'm a learner and I'm not perfect. Please tell me what is a reason behind the negative vote so that I could improve it ?

Comment: I did not downvote but it is generally expected that you make an attempt to answer the question and show what you have already done. Do you the definition of supremum of  a set of real numbers? I am sure you can answer the first part of this question without help from others.

Comment: In 2) 3) and 4) $x \to 0+$ should be changed to $\delta \to 0+$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: yes you are right. I edited it as $\delta \to 0+$ instead of $x \to 0+$. Thanks

Comment: @nicomezi:  I edited my problem. Thanks. Please give me some counter examples for options 2,3 and how to Prove option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of 4): Suppose $\omega(a,\delta) \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0+$. Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $r$ such that $0<\delta<t$ implies $\omega(a,\delta)<\epsilon$. This implies $|f(x)-f(a)| <\epsilon$  whenever $|x-a| <\delta$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$. Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $r>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a| \leq r$. This implies that $\omega(a,r) \leq \epsilon$. In fact $\omega(a,\delta) \leq \epsilon$ whenever $\delta <r$. Hence $\omega(a,\delta) \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0+$.